# Algebra -Finding value of X

Tags: analysis

Can anyone confirm answer? It doesn't tally with text book.

(100-x)^1/2 - 2x = 5

(100-x) - 4x^2 = 25

I use quadratic solver and get

x = 4.20 or 4.45

Comment: No one pointed out yet: The square of $a-b$ is not $a^2 - b^2$.  Try squaring $2-1$, and you should get $(2-1)^2 = 1$.  Compare this to $2^2-1^2 = 3$.  Squaring is not a linear function; it doesn't distribute the way multiplication by a fixed number does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solve for $x$ from;
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{(100-x)}-2x=5
\end{equation}
Re-arranging, one finds
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{(100-x)}=5+2x
\end{equation}
Upon squaring we have
\begin{equation}
(100-x)=(5+2x)^{2}
\end{equation}
Expanding
\begin{equation}
100-x=4x^{2}+20x+25
\end{equation}
Moving everything to one side yeilds,
\begin{equation}
0=4x^{2}+21x-75
\end{equation}
Now you can solve using the quadratic formula.